# I've a notice message aqppears while using compare in opencart

Tags: php, foreach, compare, opencart, notice

I've a notice message appears while using compare in opencart (when using Arabic language only - in Eng Lang it is fine -)
the message is as follows

> Notice: Undefined index: attribute in
>   /home/mmmm/public_html/store/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/compare.tpl
>   on line 116Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/mmmmm/public_html/store/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/compare.tpl
>   on line 116

compare.tpl

```
<?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $key => $attribute) { ?>
```

Please help to hide this notice

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (!empty($attribute_group['attribute']))
{
foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $key => $attribute) { ?>
...
<?php } ?> 
<?php } ?> //endforeach
<?php
 } //endif
 ?>
```